# Secure part of Spring Webapp with SSL

Tags: tomcat, ssl

We have a Spring based web application running on top of Tomcat 7. we are using Spring Security 3.1 for authentication and authorisation.

Part of the web application need to be secured with SSL connections. We understand how to enable SSL in tomcat but it will effect to the whole web app if we do it like that. People were recommending against that in various forums.

So we are looking into ways we can isolate the SSL connection to few particular URLs. We couldn;t find a good reference on how to do it. Can someone please provide info on it?

We use just tomcat, no plan to put a fully fledged web server infront of it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this at http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-ssl. Going to try it.....

Enabling SSL in Tomcat's server.xml file causes all files to be run both as secure and insecure pages, which can cause unnecessary server load. You can choose which applications offer SSL connections on a per-application basis by adding the following  element to the application's WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>YourAppsName</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This configuration allows you to set SSL options for all an application's pages in one place. For example, to disable SSL for all your application's pages, change "CONFIDENTIAL" to "NONE".

Comment: Unfortunately it still expect https connection for all pages.

Comment: Unfortunately it still expect https connection for all pages. i put             <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern> to restrict SSL only to the login page.